# Extracting cell values from columns of word document tables with automatic numbering

Tags: c#, office-interop, word-automation

I'm developing a word automation based application using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

I'm reading data from cells using this approach:

```
string strValue = tbMytable.Rows[iRowIndex].Cells[1].Range.Text;
if (strValue.Contains("\x0d\x07"))
{
    // remove cell marker
    strValue = strValue.Remove(strValue.IndexOf("\x0d\x07"), 2);
}
```

This worked for most of the tables but once I got an empty string returned by `tbMytable.Rows[iRowIndex].Cells[1].Range.Text`

When I checked manually by opening the document in Microsoft Office Word 2013, I could see values for the first column cells as `step 1`, `step 2` etc.

Upon some debugging, I figured out that it's because that table used automatic numbering for the first column (the step number string was 1 range wide). I opened the document in Word 2013 again and confirmed this.

Now how do I read the value from such a cell using `Word Interop` ?

And is there any better approach for extracting vales from cells without the cell marker other than trimming `\x0d\x07` or doing a `clmyCell.Range.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1)` ?

**EDIT:**

I have added a [sample document](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g25ad0529c423888e999811789c1cece853a016e55) [1] for clarification.

*(password for zip is `password` , without any whitespace).*

I am able to read data from all cells except the cells in the first column.

How do I read data from cells in first column (eg. the "Step 2" string) using word interop ?

[1]     http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g25ad0529c423888e999811789c1cece853a016e55

*(password for zip is `password` , without any whitespace).*

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the last details. I follow that you're extracting cell content, cutting off the end-of-cell characters. But the "how" things aren't working concerning the auto numbering isn't clear. Perhaps if you provide a more exact description of the result you expect vs. the result you're actually getting? FWIW automatic numbering is not returned in Range.Text. You can only access it through the `Paragraph` and `Paragraph.Range` objects (the properties that being with "List").

Comment: @CindyMeister I have updated my post by sharing a sample document and the specific issue there. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Unable to open the sample document ... The webpage cannot be found

Comment: @MaartenvanStam Thanks for pointing out, I have updated the link.

Comment: Blocked by SmartScreen virus protection ... I think (if your file is actually safe) put the document in a zip file for download or us a different file share option (OneDrive?)

Comment: @MaartenvanStam, I've zipped and shared. Password for ZIP is "password" without double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it on your document and here is a small example to show you how it is done in VBA

```
Sub ShowTableCellValue()

    If ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.ListParagraphs.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
    End If

End Sub
```

I guess you can translate it yourself to C#, if not shout out and I'll help you to do that as well